# Regexing help in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to check if a number is in the format 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0 , where the '_' is a number. 
For Example,

**1**9**2**9**3**7**4**2**5**4**6**2**7**4**8**8**9**0**0**

My initial though was string indexing, but I quickly discovered that it was too slow. Is there a better way using regexing in python?

Thanks in advance, 
                Arvind

Comment: Can you post your  _too slow_ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a string to test:

```
>>> q = '1929374254627488900'
```

Now, let's test it:

```
>>> q[::2] == '1234567890'
True
```

That matches.  Now, let's try one that doesn't match:

```
>>> q = '1929374254627488901'
>>> q[::2] == '1234567890'
False
```

This works because `q[::2]` returns every other character in the string and those are the characters that you are interested in testing.

#### Additional tests

Suppose we are unsure if the string is all numbers.  In that case, we add a test.  This should pass:

```
>>> q = '1929374254627488900'
>>> q[::2] == '1234567890' and q.isdigit()
True
```

While, because of the `a`, this should fail:

```
>>> q = '19293742546274889a0'
>>> q[::2] == '1234567890' and q.isdigit()
False
```

We can also test for correct length:

```
>>> q = '1929374254627488900'
>>> q[::2] == '1234567890' and q.isdigit() and len(q) == 19
True
```

Answer (score 0):

> My initial thought was string indexing, but I quickly discovered that
>   it was too slow

Most possibly you are not using the right approach

You can always use regex but, string indexing with strides can have better performance than using regex

```
st = "1929374254627488900"
st[::2] == "1234567890"
Out[93]: True
```

Comment: You need to check length as well, otherwise `st = '19293742546274889001'` will result `True` too.

Comment: In my function, I first checked the length. @niemmi

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, indexing is fast O(1)

```
>>> my_number = 1929374254627488900
>>> int(str(my_number)[1::2])
997242480 # actual number
>>> int(str(my_number)[0::2])
1234567890     #format
```